# How to set a value of type double inside an array

Tags: java, arrays, int, double

I'm doing a program as an exercise,I would like to be able to fix inside an array of double type values.
The problem that I can't solve:"
public int T[] = new int[i];".
as an error:"illegal modification of parameter T".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner tastiera = new Scanner(System.in);

        String comando;
        comando = tastiera.next();
        double soldiconto, uscita, entrata;
        int i = 0;
        soldiconto = 0;
        entrata = 0;
        uscita = 0;
        public int T[] = new int[i];


        while (i < 365) {

        System.out.println("v - versamento");
        System.out.println("p - prelievo");
        System.out.println("s - saldo");
        System.out.println("l - lista movimenti");
        System.out.println("x - exit");

        if (comando.equals("v")) { System.out.println("Quanto vuoi versare?");
        entrata = tastiera.nextInt();   
        soldiconto = soldiconto + entrata;
        T[T.length-1] = entrata;
        }


        if (comando.equals("p")) { System.out.println("Quanto vuoi prelevare?");
        uscita = tastiera.nextInt();    
        soldiconto = soldiconto - uscita;
        T[T.length-1] = -uscita;
        }


        if (comando.equals("s")) { System.out.println("Saldo: " + soldiconto);

        }

        if (comando.equals("l")) { System.out.println("Lista degli ultimi 5 movimenti:");
        System.out.println(T[T.length-5]);
        System.out.println(T[T.length-4]);
        System.out.println(T[T.length-3]);
        System.out.println(T[T.length-2]);
        System.out.println(T[T.length-1]);
        }

        if (comando.equals("x")) { 
            System.out.println("Uscita..... ");
            break;
        }
        i++;
        }

    }

}
```

I would like to be able to view the last 5 cells of the array, but it doesn't let me change the values of the individual cells.

Comment: Can you edit your question and modify the plain text and title to be in English?

Comment: Benvenuto su StackOverflow.com! Dove ".com" sta per "inglese"

Comment: I have translate the text.

Answer (score 0):

The line you intend to fix is correct. This is the line you have problems with:

```
T[T.length-1] = entrata;
```

since `entrata` is of type double and `T[T.length-1]` is an `int`. You should therefore define `entrata` to be an `int` instead of a `double`.

Another issue is that `i` is 0, so you have an array with 0 elements and assigning any values to it will result in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You might want to give a different value to `i`.